# Как я могу читать и записывать данные на диск с помощью ассемблера?

Tags: c, ассемблер

Мне нужно записывать и читать данные с диска с помощью ассемблера или си без WinAPI. Я не делаю это через Windows, я делаю это вне(мы пишем свою небольшую OS), как я могу записывать данные по секторам на диске?

Comment: вероятно, начинать надо с чтения документации к «вашей небольшой о.с.», раздел «блочный ввод/вывод»

Comment: Работая непосредственно с контроллером диска, например. Можно, конечно, на уровне вызовов BIOS, но...

Comment: И даже DOS нету? Если бы MS DOS, то там через INT 21h, я до сих пор помню, хотя 30 лет прошло. )

Comment: сначала надо написать драйвер дисковой системы. вы вообще не намекнули что хотели наверное NTFS (или FAT32 HFS ext4 btrfs ...) Или просто написать свою файл-систему.

Comment: Чтение/запись на диск сырых RAW данных, можно организовать расширенным сервисом биос int-13h (функции в регистре AH начинаются с 40h). Во-первых этот сервис эмулируют все современные UEFI, а во-вторых ему не нужна FS, т.к. в аргументах указывается номер сектора на диске.